# what is considered sex in halacha?

Tags: sexuality

Does sex is considered to be, on general laws only the penetration (anal or vaginal)?

as for example adultery, it is only considered in anal or vaginal, for my research on talmud

Comment: "Sex" is an English word with no specific legal Jewish definition. Different Jewish legal concepts have different lines regarding what actions are and aren't considered relevant for different rules. As does US law for that matter.

Comment: E.g. different things may be prohibited, but at different levels of severity.

Answer (score 1):

Any physical contact that has sensual/sexual undertones, with someone with whom sexual relations are forbidden, is prohibited as an accessory to the sin itself.

**Shulchan Arukh, Even HaEzer (20:1)**

If one has genital contact with the limb(s) of one of the "arayot" (people with whom sexual relations are forbidden), or he hugged, kissed, or benefited from nearness of their flesh, he receives (biblically sanctioned) ***lashes***, and is suspected of having relations with "arayot".

**Rema**: Note, if he had intercourse with her, whether vaginally or anally, as soon as he begins intercourse, which is defined as insertion of the glans, he is liable for ***death or excision***.